# Declare a variable from string

Tags: regex, perl

I want to include the value of below string into $QName in Perl script:

> QUEUE(SYSTEM.SELECTION.VALIDATION.QUEUE)

So I try to include `SYSTEM.SELECTION.VALIDATION.QUEUE` into `$QName`, as below code:

```
my ($QName) = /QUEUE\((\w+)\)/;
print "$QName \n";
```

However, this code not successfully produce an output.

The output should be:

> SYSTEM.SELECTION.VALIDATION.QUEUE

Comment: The `\w` does not match dots. You may match everything inside parentheses with `[^()]`, a negated bracketed character class matching any char but `(` and `)`: `my ($QName) = /QUEUE\(([^()]+)\)/;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add dots in your pattern:

```
my ($QName) = /QUEUE\(([\w.]+)\)/;
#                      ^  ^^
#                         |
#                          `--You're missing this dot:
# The "SYSTEM.SELECTION.VALIDATION.QUEUE" value comprises letters AND DOTS
```

Demo: https://ideone.com/L4FESo

Comment: @Dmitry_Egorov Thanks so much, I accept your answer, may I know what is the function of [ ] in this regex?

Comment: This doesn't compile.

Comment: @Toto: in what environment it fails to compile? Works fine on [IdeOne](https://ideone.com/L4FESo) and with my local `perl 5, version 22, subversion 0 (v5.22.0) built for x86_64-msys-thread-multi`

Comment: `$perl -we 'my ($QName) = /QUEUE\(([\w.]+)\)/;'` in a terminal gives: 
`Use of uninitialized value $_ in pattern match (m//) at -e line 1.`

Comment: This is because in my snippet I only showed the line which needs to be changed. A link to a whole test script is provided right after that. If you wish to run it from command line, try this: `$ echo 'QUEUE(SYSTEM.SELECTION.VALIDATION.QUEUE)' | perl -nlwe 'my ($QName) = /QUEUE\(([\w.]+)\)/; print $QName'`

Comment: @Toto: That is a run time error, not a compilation error.

Answer (score 0):

It is not really clear what you want to achieve but I guess you want:

```
$input_string = 'QUEUE(SYSTEM.SELECTION.VALIDATION.QUEUE)';
my ($QName) = $input_string =~ /QUEUE\((.+?)\)/;
print $QName,"\n";
```

**Output:**

```
SYSTEM.SELECTION.VALIDATION.QUEUE
```

Comment: @Azizul: Don't worry, I'm sure it is not you, I think I know who it is.